# Trouble with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with this method in `UITableView`:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

In simulator this method gets called only when a new cell appears in the `UITableView`, but on the device it gets called (after adding cells to the table) for each cell. I use images from the web in the table view and they start to load only when the current cell appears. In simulator everything works perfectly, but on the device the images start to load simultaneously, because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called for each cell. Where is the trouble? Maybe I don't understand how `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *tableCellIdentifier = @"CustomeCell";
    CMCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];

    NSMutableDictionary *currentThread = [currentThreadsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!cell)
    {
        if ([currentThread objectForKey:THREADNAME]) {
            cell = [[CMCustomCell alloc] initWithName:YES reuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];
            cell.nameLabel.text = [currentThread objectForKey:THREADNAME];
        } else {
            cell = [[CMCustomCell alloc] initWithName:NO reuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];
        }
    }

    /*HERE IS INITIALIZATION OF CELL`S FIELDS*/

    if (![currentThread objectForKey:@"thumbnailimg"]) {
        [cell.imageLoadingRoller startAnimating];
        CMImageLoader *imgLoader = [[CMImageLoader alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        [imgLoader loadImageFrom:[currentThread objectForKey:THUMBNAIL] tag:indexPath.row];
    } else {     
        [cell.imageLoadingRoller stopAnimating];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [currentThread objectForKey:@"thumbnailimg"];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This way I add new cells in table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tllAmount; ++i) {
        [currentThreadsData addObject:[threads objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [self.loadingRoller stopAnimating];

    NSMutableArray *tempData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < tllAmount; ++i) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [tempData addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [threadsTable beginUpdates];    
    [threadsTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempData withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [threadsTable endUpdates];
```

Comment: We need more code. Can you post what code you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and edit the question?

Comment: Are you saying that cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called for currently invisible cells (scrolled out of bounds)?

Comment: Yes. Firstly, after adding cells in table, cellForRowAtIndexPath called for each cell. Then begins to work correctly and calls only when cell appeared on screen.

Comment: Sounds as if you are referring to those cells somewhere in your code (e.g. in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) and hence force them to be created. A tableView by itself would never try to instantiate all cells without needing them.

Comment: My tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath contains only return 108;

Comment: for every cell thats visible, will call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I am not sure why its a problem if its being called. I am assuming that your CMImageLoader fetches the image from the internets if its not downloaded yet, and if so, it'd need to refresh the tableview (hence calling cellForRow for all the visible cells again).

Comment: If add in cellForRowAtIndexPath line: NSLog(@"%d ", [[tableView visibleCells] count]) then in console will be: 0 0 0 ... 0 (amount of 0 == amount of cells in table) and then 4 4... (when cellForRowAtIndexPath calls correctly)

Comment: I found what was the problem. I add new cells in table with insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: using UITableViewRowAnimationTop. When cells adding in table they immediately drawn on the screen and then move down with animation. At this moment calls cellForRow for each added cell! But I not understand why in simulator all is perfect...
My solution: firstly, I adding only cells that visible in current moment and after it I add other cells with UITableViewRowAnimationNone.